# In Isaiah 10:20-23 why only a remnant will remain?

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

In [Isaiah 10:20-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.10.20-23?lang=bi) who are referred to as the remnant of Israel and the escaped of the House of Jacob referenced by Hashem?  Are the remnant referenced to as only some of the Jewish people?

Why would Hashem not want all of the Jewish people to return to His Torah and Eretz Yisroel? Had the majority of the Hebrew people done something evil or contrary to Hashem and His Torah?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Arnold and it's a good question with many possible responses.

Traditional Jewish teaching is that the Prophets of the Tanach are prophecies that relate to each and every generation. So how the words apply to a given generation, hundreds or thousands of years ago, would be different from our lifetime.

But in the current context, if you look from the beginning of the chapter, it appears to be addressing the Holocaust and the massacre of the Jewish people by the Nazis. The *remnant* are those who physically survive that process.

In various Jewish writings, like Sefer Avkat Rochel of Rabbeinu Makir ben Abba Mori, book 1, sign 1-4, it refers to this time period, which is the beginning of the process of the final redemption as the *Pekidah* which is alluded to in Isaiah 10:3 and also 10:12. For whatever reason (something we cannot truly understand), G-d's wisdom decreed that it would begin in this way.

There are some who wish to relate this to the Jewish concept of *Reward and Punishment for the nation of Israel*, but there is another traditional view in Judaism that this decree, which seems to be directed toward the Jewish people, transcends that system and is simply something G-d required ***according to His wisdom, which is not like our wisdom***, as part of the final redemption. That it is really more of an assessment of how the nations of the world relate to the Jewish people, who G-d loves and cherishes, not a measure of the merit of the Jewish people themselves. This association to the re-establishment of the Monarchy of the House of David is alluded to in Isaiah 10:5 and also 10:24 which mentions the *rod and staff*, which are symbols of the Monarchy of the House of King David.

This time period is also referred to in the Talmud and other places as *the Heels of Moshiach*, and is a period when the Jewish people suffer greatly.

Concerning your last question, G-d wants all the Jewish people, in every generation, to return to His Torah and *to the land* which is an allusion to His will. And in fact, that is also G-d's promise through his Prophets. That every Jew will be included in the final redemption because like it says in Isaiah 60:21, they are all righteous in G-d's eyes. And this relates to our belief in the ultimate resurrection of the dead. Not a single Jew will ultimately be left out or forgotten like is found in Tanna D'vei Eliyahu and Pesikta Rabbati and elsewhere discussing when Moshiach ben David accepts his mission from G-d to bring about the final redemption.

Comment: Yaacov, I have a reply which is apparently too long for this comment section. I would like to reply to your kind response. Please provide a valid email address for my reply. Thank you

Comment: Isaiah 60:12
https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.60.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
כִּֽי־הַגּ֧וֹי וְהַמַּמְלָכָ֛ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר לֹא־יַעַבְד֖וּךְ יֹאבֵ֑דוּ וְהַגּוֹיִ֖ם חָרֹ֥ב יֶחֱרָֽבוּ׃ 
For the nation or the kingdom that does not serve you shall perish; such nations shall be destroyed. --------
I do pray that all Jews will be included in the final redemption which includes all relatives from the time of the writing down of the Oral Torah until His final millennium of peace on earth.
Hopefully, we will peacefully enter His reality and a complete understanding of His will

Comment: You find that the final redemption in Isaiah 60:21 all Jews shall be included in the final redemption. If you look at the entire Isaiah 60, you will see His reference to the remnant of His people. The current Talmudic Rabbinical Judaism is evidence that a second nation has formed following those men who do not serve Him but led the people away as described in Devarim 13 and Leviticus 26:27-33.
Isaiah 60:12
https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.60.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: You state that every generation will return to His Torah is G-d’s promise through His Prophets. Not the prophets, sages, Rabbinim of a second Torah but those found in the Tanach. Yes, the Torah is not totally literal but His meanings are usually metaphorical illusions to His intent. The explanations can be understood by comparing related Parshahs in the Tanach to explain His meanings for any generation. 

You affirm “That every Jew will be included in the final redemption because like it says in Isaiah 60:21, they are all righteous in G-d's eyes.

Comment: I will lay your cities in ruin and make your sanctuaries desolate, and I will not savor your pleasing odors. 
וַהֲשִׁמֹּתִ֥י אֲנִ֖י אֶת־הָאָ֑רֶץ וְשָֽׁמְמ֤וּ עָלֶ֙יהָ֙ אֹֽיְבֵיכֶ֔ם הַיֹּשְׁבִ֖ים בָּֽהּ׃ 
I will make the land desolate, so that your enemies who settle in it shall be appalled by it. 
וְאֶתְכֶם֙ אֱזָרֶ֣ה בַגּוֹיִ֔ם וַהֲרִיקֹתִ֥י אַחֲרֵיכֶ֖ם חָ֑רֶב וְהָיְתָ֤ה אַרְצְכֶם֙ שְׁמָמָ֔ה וְעָרֵיכֶ֖ם יִהְי֥וּ חָרְבָּֽה׃ 
And you will scatter among the nations, and I will unsheathe the sword against you. Your land shall become a desolation and your cities a ruin.

Comment: וַאֲכַלְתֶּ֖ם בְּשַׂ֣ר בְּנֵיכֶ֑ם וּבְשַׂ֥ר בְּנֹתֵיכֶ֖ם תֹּאכֵֽלוּ׃ 
You shall eat the flesh of your sons and the flesh of your daughters. 
וְהִשְׁמַדְתִּ֞י אֶת־בָּמֹֽתֵיכֶ֗ם וְהִכְרַתִּי֙ אֶת־חַמָּ֣נֵיכֶ֔ם וְנָֽתַתִּי֙ אֶת־פִּגְרֵיכֶ֔ם עַל־פִּגְרֵ֖י גִּלּוּלֵיכֶ֑ם וְגָעֲלָ֥ה נַפְשִׁ֖י אֶתְכֶֽם׃ 
I will destroy your cult places and cut down your incense stands, and I will heap your carcasses upon your lifeless fetishes. I will spurn you. 
וְנָתַתִּ֤י אֶת־עָֽרֵיכֶם֙ חָרְבָּ֔ה וַהֲשִׁמּוֹתִ֖י אֶת־מִקְדְּשֵׁיכֶ֑ם וְלֹ֣א אָרִ֔יחַ בְּרֵ֖יחַ נִיחֹֽחֲכֶֽם׃

Comment: Seemingly, the Creator stated that there is a result of turning away from Hashem and His Torah.
Leviticus 26:27-33
https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.27-33?lang=bi&aliyot=0  
וְאִ֨ם־בְּזֹ֔את לֹ֥א תִשְׁמְע֖וּ לִ֑י וַהֲלַכְתֶּ֥ם עִמִּ֖י בְּקֶֽרִי׃ 
But if, despite this, you disobey Me and remain hostile to Me, 
לַכְתִּ֥י עִמָּכֶ֖ם בַּחֲמַת־קֶ֑רִי וְיִסַּרְתִּ֤י אֶתְכֶם֙ אַף־אָ֔נִי שֶׁ֖בַע עַל־חַטֹּאתֵיכֶם׃ 
I will act against you in wrathful hostility; I, for My part, will discipline you sevenfold for your sins.

Comment: You are correct in stating that ‘according to another traditional view in Judaism’ is G-d’s requirements according to His wisdom which is not like our wisdom. Could it be that you are speaking of a Talmudic Rabbinical Judaism’s traditional views? ----
It is apparent that Hashem clearly stated that if Jews follow men who create laws, rules, and mitzvot that are not in His Torah, He will turn His face away from them and subject them to many eons of terrible events as delineated above.
Seemingly, the Creator stated that there is a result of turning away from Hashem and His Torah.

Comment: Examples of Talmudic Oral Laws given to Moshe for future generations.
Talmud-  Viagra  Gittin 70a:18
 https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.70a.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
Talmud- Demons, Bathrooms and Sexual Intercourse  Gittin 70:15
https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.70a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
Talmud - Pedophilia  Ketubot 11A:15
https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.11a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: And now most of the nations of the planet blame Israel for all evil. It isn’t clear that the dying remnant to which He referred were the survivors of Adolph Hitler. --------

You are correct in that we cannot truly understand His reasons for that small remnant at the final redemption but He does as stated in Isaiah 10:20-23. I assume it will be those who follow the Torah of Hashem and throw off the inane laws and rules laid down by the majority votes of men.
Examples of Talmudic Oral Laws given to Moshe for future generations.

Comment: But in the current context, if you look from the beginning of the chapter, it appears to be addressing the Holocaust and the massacre of the Jewish people by the Nazis. The remnant is those who physically survive that process.

I was speaking of the holocausts, mass tragedies, and devastations throughout the two thousand + years since the Oral Laws were first written. 
Philistines
Assyrian Empire
Babylonian Empire
Person Empire
Greek Empire
Roman Empire
Byzantine Empire
Crusaders
Spanish Empire
Nazi Germany
Soviet Union
Iran

Comment: Hashem states understanding of His Torah to all men’s נשמה thru the nostrils at the first breath of life.
https://www.sefaria.org/Job.32.8?lang=bi
 אָ֭כֵן רֽוּחַ־הִ֣יא בֶאֱנ֑וֹשׁ וְנִשְׁמַ֖ת שַׁדַּ֣י תְּבִינֵֽם׃
 But truly it is the spirit in men, the breath of Shaddai, that gives them understanding.


But in the current context, if you look from the beginning of the chapter, it appears to be addressing the Holocaust and the massacre of the Jewish people by the Nazis. The remnant are those who physically survive that process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply – (BEGINNING OF RESPONSE)
Traditional Jewish teachings by the prophets are the beliefs of every Talmudic Torah student and every Yeshiva student studying with his or her personal explanations found in His Torah. The Torah possesses clear unequivocal understandings which apply to each generation with the appropriate meanings of each era. His meanings are not ambiguous for He is Infinite Wisdom!

Comment: @ArnoldWolf I tried to read your long response via the comments. I tried to connect yesterday via a Chat Room, but you didn't follow me there. Generally, Comments under an answer are not intended for extended conversation. Piecing your comments together via the time stamps, it appears that you have issues with the Oral Torah. Is that a correct perception?

Answer (score 0):

Yeshayahu is talking about the Jews that are left over from the destruction that he prophesies will come, as he says in (10:1-3):

> ה֥וֹי הַחֹֽקְקִ֖ים חִקְקֵי־אָ֑וֶן וּֽמְכַתְּבִ֥ים עָמָ֖ל כִּתֵּֽבוּ׃
>   לְהַטּ֤וֹת מִדִּין֙ דַּלִּ֔ים וְלִגְזֹ֕ל מִשְׁפַּ֖ט עֲנִיֵּ֣י עַמִּ֑י לִהְי֤וֹת אַלְמָנוֹת֙ שְׁלָלָ֔ם וְאֶת־יְתוֹמִ֖ים יָבֹֽזּוּ׃
>   וּמַֽה־תַּעֲשׂוּ֙ לְי֣וֹם פְּקֻדָּ֔ה וּלְשׁוֹאָ֖ה מִמֶּרְחָ֣ק תָּב֑וֹא עַל־מִי֙ תָּנ֣וּסוּ לְעֶזְרָ֔ה וְאָ֥נָה תַעַזְב֖וּ כְּבוֹדְכֶֽם׃
>   בִּלְתִּ֤י כָרַע֙ תַּ֣חַת אַסִּ֔יר וְתַ֥חַת הֲרוּגִ֖ים יִפֹּ֑לוּ בְּכָל־זֹאת֙ לֹא־שָׁ֣ב אַפּ֔וֹ וְע֖וֹד יָד֥וֹ נְטוּיָֽה׃ (ס)
>
> Ha! Those who write out evil writs And compose iniquitous documents,
>   To subvert the cause of the poor, To rob of their rights the needy of My people; That widows may be their spoil, And fatherless children their booty!
>   What will you do on the day of punishment, When the calamity comes from afar? To whom will you flee for help, And how will you save your carcasses
>   From collapsing under [fellow] prisoners, From falling beneath the slain? Yet His anger has not turned back, And his arm is outstretched still.

(Sefaria’s translation)

Yeshayahu is saying that the few that survive that destruction will come back to Israel.

Comment: Lo ani, are you referencing my question or Yaacov Deane's reply to my question?

Comment: @Arnold Wolf this is referencing your question. It mostly addresses the second part of your question: “Why would Hashem not want all of the Jewish people to return to His Torah and Eretz Yisroel? Had the majority of the Hebrew people done something evil or contrary to Hashem and His Torah?” but it also answers who will come back- the few that survive this destruction that yeshayahu prophesied